# Run-time error '1004': Error when resetting cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code to reset cells on my sheet. It was fine then all of a sudden it stopped working. This is the reset code.

```
Private Sub Reset_Click()

Range(Cells(20, 2), Cells(41, 13)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Range(Cells(20, 2), Cells(41, 13)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(11, 13)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range(Cells(13, 2), Cells(18, 13)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the code in a Worksheet module?  I'm guessing you need to qualify your `Range` and `Cells` calls instead of using the globals.

Comment: As @Comintern states above.  You need to qualify the `Range` and `Cells` calls or they will be treated as being for the `ActiveSheet` which may not be the one you expect it to be

Comment: Did you protect the sheet?

Comment: I am very new to excel so i am not too sure what a Worksheet module is. However i am writing the code on the current sheet it is on so i never had to declare the worksheet first. Also when i do try to declare the worksheet i get an error.

Comment: @Rory i protected it previously but took out the code

Comment: But did you actually unprotect the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the adjusted code (which should work):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Reset_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

' Change in the following line the name of the sheet (if necessary)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range(ws.Cells(20, 2), ws.Cells(41, 13)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
ws.Range(ws.Cells(20, 2), ws.Cells(41, 13)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 2), ws.Cells(11, 13)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ws.Range(ws.Cells(13, 2), ws.Cells(18, 13)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
```

Basically, you should qualify all of your `Range` and `Cells` with the applicable `workbook` and `worksheet`. Otherwise, you leave it to VBA to guess which Excel file to use and which sheet in the file should be altered.

<sub>Since, this is a community effort with the comments above, I'll make this answer an community wiki answer.</sub>

Comment: when i type that in i get this error. Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: Did you change the sheet name in the code (as commented in the code)? Most likely your sheet is not named `Sheet1` but has a different name?!

Comment: If you have only one sheet in your file (as mentioned in a comment above) then you can also use `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` instead of `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

Comment: I changed it to this Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2(2)")

Comment: If the name of your sheet is `Sheet2(2)` then it should work now. Otherwise, you can also use `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` (as mentioned above) since you have only one sheet in your file. BTW, we are not too much interested how you changed the names of sheets in the code but we are much rather interested if your problem got resolved by this answer. If so, please mark this answer as accepted so we can move on.

Answer (score 0):

How many sheets do you have?? If you don't clarify the location of the range, you will get an error.
Try something like:

```
   Sheets("NameOfTheSheetWhereTheRangeIsLocated").Range(Cells(20, 2), Cells(41, 13)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
```

Comment: I have only 1 sheet.

Comment: Try to not create a private sub if don't do it in a worksheet module. You create a worksheet module by clicking on the sheet name in the editor. if you created just a normal module just try to change your private sub into a public sub and specify the sheet.

Comment: @Ary: I'd like to make a suggestion to improve upon your solution: you are suggesting to qualify the code (which is correct and good). Yet, you are one step short of fully qualifying your code yourself. Your solution qualifies the sheet but not (yet) the workbook (Excel file) to work on. This solution can (potentially) lead to a very similar problem in the future. To fully qualify your code you should include `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfTheSheetWhereTheRangeIsLocated")...`.

Comment: @Ralph, thank you :) ! Honestly, I use much more this syntax: `NameOfMySheet.Range(...) `, so I completely forgot that it is better to fully qualify the code by adding `ThisWorkbook` in this case !

Answer (score -1):

It is always safe to write the code in a module rather wring the same in a worksheet module.due to limitations in excel this kind of error occurs.