# Need code in excel for button to subtract time in cell

Tags: excel, time, vba

Can anyone help me please. I am using excel to create a hockey simulator and I need a way (maybe a button?) to take time off of the game clock.

For example cell D4 would start at 20:00, I need a button to take off :20 (twenty seconds) away from the clock every time I click it. So click and the time would display 19:40 then click button again it would display 19:20, then click and 19:00, then click and 18:40, ect.. all the way down to 0:00. Then it needs to reset back to 20:00 for the next period.

I am thinking that a button would work but if there is a different way I would be interested as long as it makes the game clock go down :20 second every time I need it to go down.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the button to your spreadsheet from the developer menu/toolbox in excel.

You'll need to format your cell as Custom using [m]:ss

Then in the code for your button you can use:

```
Sub ChangeGameClock()

Range("D4").Value = DateAdd("s", -20, Range("D4").Value)

If Range("D4").Value = "0" Then
Range("D4").Value = "0:20:00"
End If

End Sub
```

Good luck

Comment: While it is certainly a nice move from your side to provide VBA code to someone who (seemingly) hasn't written any code of his / her own, you should still strive to provide a complete answer. The above solution does not include whether an ActiveX button or a Form Control has been (should be) used. Also, you should note that - if a form control is used then - the button needs to be assigned the above macro. Also, please fully qualify your code snippet. As it is provided above it will surely lead to more problems / questions in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39854381/1153513

Comment: thanks so much for the quick reply. I have switched cell D4 to custom mm:ss but it automatically switches the 20:00 I enter into the cell as 00:00 and in the text box shows 8:00:00 PM. I have closed the sheet and redid this several times but it just switches it back. I even entered the same info into another cell after switching that cell to custom mm.ss and it does the same thing.. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try to enter `0.83333333333333` or `=20/24` into cell D4 and then format it to `Time`. That should work. For more information you might want to read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000194/difference-between-date-and-time-w-out-work-week-excel/38001028#38001028

Comment: thanks Ralph... I edited the cell to be =20/24 and it shows 20:00 in the cell.   But does switching this break the code because I am getting a runtime error 13 type mismatch error...

Comment: It shouldn't have an impact on the code. It will merely change the value in `D4` (obviously) as this is what the above code is supposed to do. So, once you hit the button (run the macro) there will be no longer `=20/24` in there. But that's the point. Actually the above solution could be shortened to only one line: `Range("D4").Value = DateAdd("n", -20, Range("D4").Value)` (which removes 20 minutes from `D4`). The rest of the code is only to reset the time.

Comment: The original code wasn't working correctly as it was taking 1 second away every 4 or 5 clicks. So I adjusted it like this and now it is taking :20 seconds away every click and when it goes to 0:00 the next click takes it back to 20:00. I will do more testing today to make sure it all works.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim cell As Range
Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(33, "M")

cell.Value2 = DateAdd("s", -1200, cell.Value2)

If cell.Value2 <= 0 Then cell.Value2 = TimeSerial(20, 0, 0)

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

'Set the cell to work on as cell D4 on the sheet
'   with the name Sheet1. You might have to change
'   the sheet name if your sheet is named differently.
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, "D")

'Remove 20 seconds from D4
cell.Value2 = DateAdd("s", -20, cell.Value2)
's stands for seconds as outlined here:
'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251759(v=office.15).aspx

'If D4 is 0 or less then it should be reset to 20 minutes
If cell.Value2 <= 0 Then cell.Value2 = TimeSerial(0, 20, 0)

End Sub
```

How to use the above code: copy the code into an empty module into your Excel file. Then you can add a new (form control)  button to your sheet and assign the above macro (currently named `tmpSO`) to the button. If you are using an ActiveX button instead then you should double-click on the button after you have inserted the button. Then the VBE will pop-up with something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub
```

Just change that to

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Set the cell to work on as cell D4 on the sheet
'   with the name Sheet1. You might have to change
'   the sheet name if your sheet is named differently.
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, "D")

'Remove 20 seconds from D4
cell.Value2 = DateAdd("s", -20, cell.Value2)
's stands for seconds as outlined here:
'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251759(v=office.15).aspx

'If D4 is 0 or less then it should be reset to 20 minutes
If cell.Value2 <= 0 Then cell.Value2 = TimeSerial(0, 20, 0)

End Sub
```

Afterwards, your ActiveX button should work too.